# Android Firebase RecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to display my data from Firebase database into a recyclerview using Firebase RecyclerAdapter. I am quite new to this and looked around a lot. But I can't figure out what's wrong here. The println in PopulateViewHolder, I added it there to see if the function was working and it doesn't print anything. Neither does the one in the DeviceModel. Here is my code for the class where it all happens:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class RecievedKeys extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    User user = new User();
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Shared_with").child(user.getUid());

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recieved_keys);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.relLayout);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DeviceModel, DeviceViewHolder> firebaseRecAdapter = new
                FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DeviceModel, DeviceViewHolder>(DeviceModel.class, R.layout.device,
                        DeviceViewHolder.class, mDatabaseRef) {

                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(DeviceViewHolder viewHolder, DeviceModel model, int position) {
                        System.out.println("ViewHolder");
                        viewHolder.setName(model.getDevice_name());
                        viewHolder.setDevice_MAC(model.getDevice_MAC());
                    }
                };
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecAdapter);
    }



    private class DeviceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mView;
        public DeviceViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }
            public void setName(String mName){
            TextView name = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            name.setText(mName);
            }

        public void setDevice_MAC(String macAdd){
            TextView mac = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.MAC);
            mac.setText(macAdd);
        }

        }
    }
`
```

This is my layout file:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rootRel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/relLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my model for recycleradapter:

```
public class DeviceModel {
    private String Device_MAC;
    private String Password;
    private String Device_name;

    public DeviceModel() {
    }

    public String getDevice_MAC() {
        System.out.println(Device_MAC+"From getter");
        return Device_MAC;
    }

    public void setDevice_MAC(String device_MAC) {
        Device_MAC = device_MAC;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        Password = password;
    }

    public String getDevice_name() {
        return Device_name;
    }

    public void setDevice_name(String device_name) {
        Device_name = device_name;
    }
}
```

This is the db Structure of the node I am trying to display:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCU6Z.png)

All I am getting is a blank screen. No errors, or anything to even point me somewhere. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are defining `mDatabaseRef` using `user.getUid()`.  `user` is defined on the previous line: `user = new User()`.  Are you confident that this produces a valid database reference? Post the constructor for `User()`.

Comment: Yeah. I tried defining it in the onCreate method as well. No avail

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo.  You use `child("Shared_with")`, database  uses `Shared_With` (uppercase W).

Also, your database does not contain instances of `DeviceModel`.  The names of the fields in your database must correspond to the names in your model.  Looks at the description in the [FirebaseUI documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#creating-a-model-class).  For the getter/setter names you have defined in your model, the database instances should contain:  device_MAC, password, device_Name.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed that and it gave a lot of errors and the app crashed. There is something now at least

Comment: Example in the [FirebaseUI docs](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-firebaseui-to-populate-a-recyclerview).

Comment: Okay the errors just disappeared and the app isn't crashing anymore. Back to what it was doing. Nothing.